# Mock API in Unit Tesing on Nativescript Core

Tags: api, unit-testing, mobile, mocking, nativescript

I'm implementing unit testing in my mobile app project with nativescript core. I want to mock api in unit testing but I can't do it, So this is my code

```
// model that I want to test
const myfunction = async (): Promise<myInterface> => {
  const response = await fetch("myURL", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  });
  const { status, data }: { status: string, data?: any } = await response.json();
  if (!status || status !== "ok") {
    throw new Error("failed fetching from host, status:" + status);
  }

  return data;
}
```

```
// my unit testing

import * as dataModel from "../../../shared/models/data";

describe('data', () => {
  describe('myfunction', () => {
    it('get data from api', async () => {
      try {
        // I want to mock api in this place
        const response = await dataModel.myfunction();
      } catch(err) { console.log(err); }
    });
  });
});
```

Does it have some plugin or something that can mock api from fetch with this mobile app nativescript core?

Comment: No it doesn't have any built-in mechanism. Probably you could add an interceptor code to your fetch calls, point them to local JSON files instead of actual API to mock the response.

Comment: @Manoj thank you, I'm understand your concept, but question is  how to do? do you have example for me?

Comment: Just don't call the fetch method directly, have your own method (interceptor), pass an additional param / based on env variable, point the url to local JSON.

Comment: ok, got it. thank you for your comment :)